# Condition doesn't work and still submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I got this condition in form where I must check 2 password input, the first one is firstpass and the second one is for password confirmation

**I want both of this inputs have the same value and got more than 7 characters**

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(form).submit(function(event){
if (f_pass.value.length < 7){
event.preventDefault();
// show error and friendly error notification 
fpassCond = false;
}
else if (f_pass.value == ''){
event.preventDefault();
// show error and friendly error notification 
fpassCond = false;
}
else {
// show green message for validation and green border in the input
fpassCond = true;
}

if (c_pass.value.length < 7){
event.preventDefault();
// show error and friendly error notification 
cpassCond = false;
}
else if (c_pass.value == ''){
event.preventDefault();
// show error and friendly error notification 
cpassCond = false;
}
else {
// show green message for validation and green border in the input
cpassCond = true;
}


// last condition before submitting form

if (fpassCond == true && cpassCond == true) {
    form.submit();
} else{
    event.preventDefault();
// show errors
}
})
```

but when I try to run it,
I input the first pass, 8 characters
** the cpass is empty**

Still able to submit it

What went wrong?

Comment: i guess you need to `return false;` if fpassCond is false

Comment: also where and how is you `f_pass` and further variables defined?

Comment: or perhaps can we use like this ?? 

` if ((fpass && cpass).value.length < 7) {

}`

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs to have an event in parameter list

```
$(form).submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: yes I knew, but I want to verify the form before submitting


for each input I use condition and Cond == true / false 

and using event.preventDefault();
but for this password, it's not working

Comment: It is showing the errors and also submitting the form right?

Comment: yes, but I want it to show error and stop submitting form, so user can re-check their data before submitting the form

Comment: Is it going in the if condition?? console.log both if and else and see where is it going to.

Comment: I think I get it now hehe

Comment: Great. If my answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Best to have the browser help you with some simple validation first. Add `min="7"` to your input to have the browser not submit the form if the length is not 7 or more. Here is a Pseudocode:

```
// Browser is making sure f_pass and c_pass is about 7 letters or more
const firstPass = f_pass.value; 
const secondPass = c_pass.value;

if (firstPass !== secondPass) {
  e.preventDefault();
// continue your error handling here
} else {
 // both pass is valid and the same, continue
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but the event bubbling keep showing up and 'break' the costum made notification I made